# Converting conditional vimscript mapping into lua (neovim) (submit <CR> in lua)

Tags: vim, lua, neovim

I am trying to convert the following conditional mapping from vimscript to lua:

```
:nnoremap <expr> <CR> ((&buftype is# "quickfix") ? "<CR>" : ":\:nohlsearch<cr>\n")
```

This mapping maps <kbd>Enter</kbd> to a `:nohlsearch` command, but only if we are not in the `quickfix` buffer. There, you need the <kbd>Enter</kbd> for selecting lines.

The lua code that I came with is:

```lua
vim.keymap.set("n", "<CR>", function()
if vim.bo.buftype == "quickfix" then
  print("<CR>")
  vim.api.nvim_input("<CR>")
else
  print("nohlsearch")
  vim.cmd(":nohlsearch")
end
end, {desc = "call :nohlsearch to disable highlighting (but only if in file editing)"} )
```

The branching, the `vim.cmd`, and the `print()` parts work as expected, but the `vim.api.nvim_input("<CR>")` part doesn't work (in quickfix I can't use <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select a line). It's not equivalent to the `<CR>` in the vimscript mapping.

Also, there has to be a more idiomatic way to write this mapping.

I started this conversion because I need to make the condition more complex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to check the doc of `vim.keymap.set` more thoroughly (see `:h vim.keymap.set`). You are doing it wrong and missing some parameters. Here is what is working (tested in nvim 0.7.2):

```lua
vim.keymap.set('n', '<CR>', function()
  if vim.o.buftype == 'quickfix' then
    return "<CR>"
  else
    return ":nohlsearch<CR>"
  end
end, {expr = true, replace_keycodes = true})
```

You can just return those key maps in the lua code, but you are missing the `{expr = true, replace_keycodes = true}` part.

If you haven't check [nvim lua guide](https://github.com/nanotee/nvim-lua-guide#vimkeymap), read it through and make sure you understand all of it. You will understand nvim better than most users.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer and for pointing me to the documentation where I can learn why it works 

Comment: Wouldn't you need ```noremap = true``` as well to match OP's original vimscript?
Edit: Nevermind, ```remap``` is defaulted to false, and thus ```noremap``` is defaulted to true. See ```:h vim.keymap.set```.